# Parse HTML Tag within p and img src tag

Tags: android, html, json, jsoup

```
<p><a href="..\Uploads\Greenergy-Newsletter.pdf"><img src="..\/Uploads/download_pdf.jpg" alt="" width="147" height="133" /></a></p>
```

How to fetch href and img src tag data in string format.I tried jsoup library.
But did not get the exact solutions.
Please help me 
Thank you

Comment: <p><a href=\\\"..\/Uploads\/Greenergy-Newsletter.pdf\\\"><img src=\\\"..\/Uploads\/download_pdf.jpg\\\" alt=\\\"\\\" width=\\\"147\\\" height=\\\"133\\\" \/><\/a><\/p>"

Comment: Please update your question with proper what you want ?

Comment: better tag it with java too

Comment: Try jQuery's attr() function

Comment: I want "\Uploads\Greenergy-Newsletter.pdf" with respect to a href tag and "/Uploads/download_pdf.jpg" with respect to img src tag

Comment: Please edit your question and put all relevant infos into it. The comments are not a good place for additional vital information. State clearly what you want, what you get and how you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

First select element by tag p and save it in doc.Then:

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]"); // a with href
Elements pngs = doc.select("img[src$=.jpg]");
// img with src ending .jpg
```

Hope this helps